# FF XIII-2 Cemetary

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

So, I'm in the cemetary of Bresha ruins (when it's snowing) and there's a man with a red silhouette and I don't know what to do. I try everything, even throw Mog and nothing happens. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, nevermind. I got it. You just gotta synch with the guy. I don't know why it didn't work the first time.